# MongoDB upsert with empty update document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to figure out how to insert a document into a collection iff the document is not already present in that collection. If the document is already present, the statement should be a no-op.

The approach I'm taking it to use an upsert with an empty update document:

```
db.collection.update({ ...query... }, { }, { upsert: true })
```

But Mongo tells me that "Update documents cannot be empty". How can I accomplish this without needlessly updating the existing document? Thanks.

Edit: My query document looks like this:

```
{
    "Chromosome" : "4",
    "Position" : 60000,
    "Identifier" : "rs1345",
    "ReferenceAllele" : "N"
}
```

Comment: I added a specific example.

Comment: Thanks. Do you need all of those fields in your query to uniquely identity the doc?

Comment: Yes, it's a four-part key. I have a unique index on the collection, so the lookup is quick enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by using [`$setOnInsert`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) in your update object which will only apply in the case the upsert results in an insert:

```js
var query = {
    "Chromosome" : "4",
    "Position" : 60000,
    "Identifier" : "rs1345",
    "ReferenceAllele" : "N"
};
db.collection.update(query, {$setOnInsert: query}, {upsert: true})
```

Comment: Thanks. I considered that, but doesn't it double the amount of time needed for the insert?

Comment: It shouldn't as the way it works is that Mongo simply combines the query key parameter and the `$setOnInsert` value to create the document to insert. It's still just a single operation.

Comment: Ah, perfect. Will use this, then. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnnyHK so you are confirming that it does in fact take the extra work of combining the $setOnInsert parameter with itself

Answer (score 0):

Create a unique index on the fields you use in the query, then use insert. If an identical document already exists, the insert will fail.

(You may want an index anyway to make this operation fast)